# a single word for a person who wins prize

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to know a word that stands for a person who gets on the stage and receives award.If I were an announcer or a presenter,how would I invite persons who win prizes to the stage...Can I just say...First prize winner, Mr...., Please come on over to receive 1st prize?

Comment: Sure you can. If you need another word, try, "Please welcome our (first) champion"

Comment: And the winner is....

Comment: Or prize-winner

Comment: If you were in _Dolby Theatre_, you could simply say "the prize goes to...". :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to 'laureate', which refers to an important prize, [awardee](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/award?q=awardee#award__15) is also fine, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

There's the word [laureate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laureate) :

> someone who has won an important prize or honor for achievement in an art or science