# Word for a person who had been given an award

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is a single word that you can use for a person who had been given an award?

Comment: What sort of award? A medal? A trophy? An Amazon gift voucher?

Comment: The winner? …..

Comment: _Recipient_ of an award?

Comment: Duplicate: [A single word for a person who wins a prize](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251297/a-single-word-for-a-person-who-wins-prize/251332#251332).

Answer (score 6):

[Honouree](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/honouree) (or *honoree* if you're American) - One who receives an honour or award.

One might also say *awardee*, but in my experience *honouree* is more common.

Answer (score 2):

Awardee

> a person who is given money, a prize, etc. by an official organization https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/awardee

Answer (score 1):

[Prizewinner](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prizewinner), maybe? More specificity regarding what context you're using this in would help you get a better answer, though.

Comment: My problem was to find a word that wasn't winner, as this was an award and not a prize.  Thesaurus.com was no help.  Someone has given "recipient" that works for me.  But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Laureate.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laureate)

> In English, the word laureate has come to signify eminence or association with literary awards or military glory. It is also used for recipients of the Nobel Prize, the Gandhi Peace Award, the Student Peace Prize, and for former music directors of orchestras who retain some level of involvement.

> In ancient Greece, the laurel (Laurus nobilis) was sacred to Apollo, and as such, sprigs of it were fashioned into a crown or wreath of honor for poets and heroes.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laureate) This symbolism has been widespread ever since. "Laureate letters" in old times meant the dispatches announcing a victory; and the epithet was given, even officially (e.g. to John Skelton) by universities, to distinguished poets.[2]

> The name of "bacca-laureate" for a bachelor's degree shows a confusion with a supposed etymology from Latin bacca lauri (the laurel berry), which, though incorrect, involves the same idea.

Comment: Thanks.  A good word, but I was looking for a less-sophisticated word and Thesaurus.com was no help.  Someone has given "recipient" that works for me.